# IOS How to parse the xml retrieve the element to put in an array and display in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap, nsxmlparser

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");
    output= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //    NSString *severity = @"Informational";
    NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                            " <IncidentGetList xmlns=\"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/\">"
                             "<Severity></Severity>"
                             "<SourceOrganization></SourceOrganization>"
                             "<DestinationOrganization></DestinationOrganization>"
                            "<MaxIncidents></MaxIncidents>"
                             "<SourceIP></SourceIP>"
                             "<Category></Category>"
                             "<ExcludeCategory></ExcludeCategory>"
                             "<StartTimeStampGMT></StartTimeStampGMT>"
                             "<EndTimeStampGMT></EndTimeStampGMT>"
                             "<CustomerSeverity></CustomerSeverity>"
                             "</IncidentGetList>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.monitoredsecurity.com/SWS/incidents.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/IncidentGetList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    if(connection)
    {
        webResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection is NULL");
    }

    // Menu View
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    // Insert Navigation Bar

    //    [self insertNavBarWithScreenName:SCREEN_INCIDENT];
    //    
    //    CGRect frm = btnDownArrow.frame;
    //    frm.origin.x = 185;
    //    frm.origin.y = 42;
    //    [btnDownArrow setFrame:frm];
    //    [self.navBarView addSubview:btnDownArrow];
    //    
    //   
    //    
    //    [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:self.view];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");
    [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Data recieved");

    // NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];

    // NSLog(responseString);
    // [response setText:responseString];

    //[status setText:@"Response retrieved async"];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Received %lu Bytes", (unsigned long)[webResponseData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                        [webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    //now parsing the xml
    NSData *myData = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];

    //setting delegate of XML parser to self
    xmlParser.delegate = self;
    [xmlParser parse];
    // Run the parser
    @try{
        BOOL parsingResult = [xmlParser parse];
        NSLog(@"parsing result = %hhd",parsingResult);
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception)
    {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:[exception reason] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
}

//Implement the NSXmlParserDelegate methods
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    //currentElement = elementName;
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    strCaptured = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Severity"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Log Output%@",[item objectForKey:@"Severity"]);
    }

    currentElement = elementName;

    //NSLog(@"current element: ", elementName);
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"File found and parsing started");

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [strCaptured appendString:string];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Severity  "]) {
        [output addObject:[item copy]];
    } else {
        [item setObject:strCaptured forKey:elementName];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    if (errorParsing == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"XML processing done!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error occurred during XML processing");
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
    return [output count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellId = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text= [output objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you can refer this link for appropriate solution..<http://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/>. Hope it helps if not I can provide u code if required.

Answer (score 0):

Make an file in NSObject then use Methods in Parsing

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
  {
  }

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser parseErrorOccurred: (NSError *) parseError {
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName
  namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName
  attributes: (NSDictionary *) attributeDict{
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didEndElement: (NSString *) elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI
  qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName{


if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"webResponseData"])
{
    [communication addObject:[currentElement stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];   
}
currentElement = nil;   
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters: (NSString *) string {

if(!currentElement)
    currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElement appendString:string];
}
```

Then in connectiondidfinishloading in viewcontroller import parser file and make object of file
example :-

```
NSString *responseStringCommunication=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:MutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Parser *parser=[[Parser alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *array=[parser parse:responseStringCommunication];
```

Comment: it would be better if you design your code while you giving answer. (at lease if else condition code)

Comment: Hey, Can you be more specific by show how to create NSObject then use NSObject to parse? Im a beginner in objective C. kindly show the steps. thank you!

Comment: what is the communication attribute for? where to declare it.

Comment: [currentElement appendString:string]; 
has an error on the appendString. the error says @interface for NSString declares the selector 'appendstring'

Comment: I have updated my codes to more neat. please go over to this question title 
"IOS How to retrieve one of the element in xml after calling success and put it into an array to display on tableview"